# Is it possible to place objects with hit test without plane detection?

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

Following Apple's [Creating an Immersive AR Experience with Audio](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/creating_an_immersive_ar_experience_with_audio)
, I thought it would be interesting to experiment and try to place objects anywhere and not just on a vertical and horizontal plane. Is it at all possible to place an object using touch without plane detection? I understand that plane detection would increase the accuracy of hit tests and ARAnchor detection, so would there be any way where one could perform hit tests on any other location in the scene?

Answer (score 0):

If your AR scene already contains any 3D geometry in a current session you can definitely use **[hit-testing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnview/2875544-hittest)** to place a new model there (a placement based on already contained 3D geometry), or you can use feature points for model's placement (if any).

If there's no 3D geometry at all in your AR scene, or there's a extremely *sparse point cloud*, what do you apply hit-testing method to? Hit-test is a projected 2D point from screen-space onto a 3D surface (remember, detected planes are hidden 3D planes), or onto any appropriate **[feature point](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnview/2875544-hittest)**.

**So, in AR, plane detection is crucial when developer is using hit-testing**.

```
func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, 
               types: ARHitTestResult.ResultType) -> [ARHitTestResult]
```

> Here you can see all the [ARHitTestResult.ResultType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arhittestresult/resulttype/2875708-featurepoint) available.

But pay attention to this, there's a hitTest method returning `SCNHitTestResult`:

```
func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, 
             options: [SCNHitTestOption : Any]?) -> [SCNHitTestResult]
```

## Usage:

```
let touchPosition: CGPoint = gesture.location(in: sceneView)

let hitTestResult = sceneView.hitTest(touchPosition, 
                                      types: .existingPlaneUsingExtent)
```

or:

```
let hitTestResult = sceneView.hitTest(touchPosition, 
                                      types: .featurePoint)
```

[image]

Also, hit-testing is actively used in 3D games but it's rather for VR there than for AR.

Comment: Thanks. So, saying it on my own, a hit test is mainly a function that determines a geographical 2D plane, not a 3D plane. ARKit builds a coarse point cloud to understand the 3D world around the user, and these are then considered anchors that are possibly a part of real-world planes. What I'm still unsure of is: can I perform a hit test on a non-2D plane? For example, placing a 3D object in the air instead of on a surface.

Comment: You can place 3D object in the air without using hit-testing. For this you can use a transform matrix of ARCamera + some z-distance.